# How to concatenate macros in CPP

Tags: c, macros, concatenation, c-preprocessor

```
#define STR1 "NEW"
#define STR2 PILLAR
#define MAKE_STR(x) #x
#define STR3 STR1 MAKE_STR(STR2)
printf(STR3 " hello world\n");
```

The above statement expands to

```
printf("NEWSTR2 hello world\n");
```

I need something like "NEWPILLAR hello world". Any inputs?

Comment: Actually, the macro expands to `printf("NEW" "STR2" " hello world\n");`.  Use the -E flag of your compiler (or equivalent) to invoke only the preprocessor; don't assume that what printf prints is what the preprocessor does.

Answer (score 0):

Just expand `STR2` before string-ifying it.

```
#define STR1 "NEW"
// #define STR2 PILLAR
#define STR2 MAKE_STR(PILLAR)
#define MAKE_STR(x) #x
// #define STR3 STR1 MAKE_STR(STR2)
#define STR3 STR1 STR2
printf(STR3 " hello world\n");
```

Or, if you really need to define `STR2` from somewhere else:

```
#define EXPAND_MAKE_STR(x) MAKE_STR(x)
#define STR3 STR1 EXPAND_MAKE_STR(STR2)
```

Comment: Did exactly the same thing, but i still see the same problem.

Comment: I think the problem seems to be the STR2. Your code works exactly as it is supposed to.
The define STR2 is passed from a makefile so if i replace this statement with
#define STR2 PILLAR
#define MK_STR2 MAKE_STR(STR2)
I read the print as 
=> NEWSTR2 hello world

Comment: @CPPGuy I tested the code in my answer and it gave the desired result.

Comment: #define STR1 "NEW"
#define STR2 PILLAR
#define MAKE_STR(x) #x
#define MK_STR2 MAKE_STR(STR2)
#define STR3 STR1 MK_STR2
printf(STR3 " hello world\n");
Can you try this please?

Comment: @CPPGuy: Defining the macros from a makefile adds a whole extra level of complexity — the shell gets in the way and has meanings for double quotes, single quotes and unquoted hashes (`#`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I understand it, the define is passed in an unquoted hash and it needs to be passed that way because of other dependencies. I have simplified the problem for the ease of understanding.

Comment: @CPPGuy Try my new solution.

Comment: @iBug Thanks a lot. It worked. You are just awesome.

Comment: @CPPGuy You can accept the answer if you find it useful.

Comment: @iBug In the same way is there a way to concatenate a define from makefile with another define?
say 
#define STR1 NEW
#define STR2 PILLAR //from makefile
#define STR3 STR1 ## STR2 => will result in NEWSTR2 not NEWPILLAR

Comment: @CPPGuy Would you please edit your question to add that in so I can answer it?

Comment: @iBug never mind figured it out. I think the real problem is the preprocessor will only expand the macros recursively if neither the stringizing operator # nor the token-pasting operator ## are applied to it. So, you have to use some extra layers of indirection.